# launch a program out of the executable location

Tags: bash, terminal, exec, osx-mavericks

I want to know how to launch my C program from any location in bash shell.

I tried defining an alias in `.bash_profile` file in my home folder.

Y try with:

1) `exec /Users/memmaker650/Desktop/Scripts/script_renombrar_series/name`

Error given by ther bash shell

```
-bash: /Users/memmaker650/Desktop/Scripts/script_renombrar_series/name: No such file or directory 
-bash: exec: /Users/memmaker650/Desktop/Scripts/script_renombrar_series/name: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

2) `./Users/memmaker650/Desktop/Scripts/script_renombrar_series/name`

Error given by ther bash shell

```
-bash: ./Users/memmaker650/Desktop/Scripts/script_renombrar_series/name: No such file or directory
```

But both doesn't works.
What i'm doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Care to specify the error given by the shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does that file exist?  Can you see it if you do

`ls /Users/memmaker650/Desktop/Scripts/script_renombrar_series/name`?

You probably don't need to use exec, as that will replace your existing shell process, and you don't need a starting . (as you have in ex. 2), as that will try to execute a shell script (but not a compiled executable) in-line.
What happens if you just type the full pathname

`/Users/memmaker650/Desktop/Scripts/script_renombrar_series/name`?

Comment: +1 His leading `.` is part of the path, not the shell `source` command, but the final suggestion is correct.

Comment: yeah, there's an stupid error with the path, my account is memmaker6501 and not memmaker650. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Add the path "Users/memmaker650/Desktop/Scripts/script_renombrar_series" to your PATH variable then you should be able to launch as "name" directly